# How to display 12 product in listing page?

Tags: magento-1.9

in my website i used new product, feature product etc.. on that page 12 product not showing it showing only 9 product, so that i used custom code but it's not working

```
<?php $magentoCurrentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>

<?php $magentoCurrentUrlArr = @explode("?",$magentoCurrentUrl);
$magentoCurrentUrl = $magentoCurrentUrlArr[0];
$magentoPageLimit = "";
if($magentoCurrentUrlArr[1])
{
    $magentoPageLimit = @explode("=",$magentoCurrentUrlArr[1]);
    $magentoPageLimit = $magentoPageLimit[0];
}

if($magentoPageLimit == "" || $magentoPageLimit != "limit")
{
    $_productCollection->setPageSize(12);
}
```

But default listing page it's working fine how i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

may be other product not visible at frontend because of some reason. this reason may be one of this

-the product is assigned to a category

-the product is assigned to a store view.

-the product is In Stock

-the product has a qty assigned

Comment: No that category have more then 80 products

Comment: echo  $_productCollection->getSize(); and check total no of product

Comment: is i set 24 it will show 24 product if i set 12 it will display only 9

Comment: if you comment setPageSize() then what's the result??

Comment: same 9 product will display

Comment: i think other product not visible for some of the reason. you have to check out why may be there visibility is set  not visible individual